# Modular transformations of the coupling constant of a CFT

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conformal-field-theory

Consider a CFT on a cylinder of circumference $L$ and some coupling $\mu$ such that $\mu/L^{2}$ is a dimensionless constant.

The thermal CFT on the cylinder with temperature $1/\beta$ is equivalent to the CFT on a torus with periods $L$ and $\beta$.

---

Using the $S$-transformation on the torus CFT, we find that

$$Z(\beta, L) = Z(- L, \beta) = Z(- \beta, - L) = Z( L, - \beta) = Z(\beta, L).$$

This means that, under the $S$-transformation on the torus CFT, we have that

$$Z(\beta, L, \mu) = Z(L, \beta, \mu) = Z(L, \lambda\beta, \lambda^{2}\mu) = Z(L, L^{2}/\beta, \mu L^{2}/\beta^{2}) = Z(4\pi^{2}/\beta, L, \mu\ 4\pi^{2}/\beta^{2}).$$

---

Consider now the partition function $Z(\beta, L, \mu, \theta)$ with angular potential $\theta$. How would you expect this partition function to $S$-transform?